# openPrimaryTab in the default console not working

Tags: integration, console

I have a button that is opening a new tab in the console. It was working just fine most of last year, but has stopped working and errors now.

Have they removed support for opening tabs with console integration?

URL_LINK is a sfdc url, I have also tried changing the url to just google.com or salesforce.com and get the same results.

code:
`{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/support/console/35.0/integration.js")} 
 if(sforce.console && sforce.console.isInConsole()){
    sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(null,URL_LINK, true);
 }`

errors:
In js console:

> Service Cloud Toolkit API cannot be used with your browser.

In popup on browser:

> Cannont read property 'call' of undefined.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @ScottH, did you manage to find out what happened with this? I'm using API 37.0 with latest Chrome 51.0.2704.103 (64-bit). Same error.

Comment: @RohitKunal I've been trying to figure out the root cause for this pretty mysterious error but can never get it to appear on my side. If you have some details about your implementation or repro steps it would help to figure it out. Especially if you're able to make it appear with a relatively simple implementation in a sandbox or a new DE org.

Comment: Or if anyone else is experiencing this, search the JS for code with a line that looks like this "n.usePostMessage() ? (l = n.registry," and set a breakpoint and let me know what value you see for the variables n, n.usePostMessage(), window.Sfdc, Sfdc, and Sfdc.xdomain. It will help pinpoint where the toolkit is seeing a problem.